# Aggregate Function Group by Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following is how I have created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
  [Counter] int
  ,Per date not null
  ,Cam float
  ,CamMeg float
  ,Hfx float
  ,HfxMet float
  ,TorMetric float

)
```

The following is how I call the table later on in my script:

```
SELECT 
  ((ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Per desc)-1)/@Avg)+1 as [Counter], Per, 
  Cam, 
  AVG(CamMetric) as CamMet, 
  HfxMe, 

FROM #tmp
GROUP BY [counter] ;

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

The following are the errors that I get:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 175
>   Column '#tmp.Per' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 175
>   Column '#tmp.Per' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What am I doing incorrectly?

The data looks like the following

```
counter --- per ---Cam --- HfxMet ---......

 1        2012-02-09      3       16
 1        2012-02-24      4       12
 1        2012-03-04      2       15
 2        2012-03-15      1       18
 2        2012-03-30      6       20
 2        2012-04-07      10      6
 3        2012-04-28      8       3
```

Now I want to add two more columns called CamMetricAvg and HfxMetric that will look at all counters that are 1 and then get the CamMetric and HfxMetric values respectively and give the average and put that on each Like the following:

```
counter --- per ---Cam --- CamMt ---

 1        2012-02-09      3         3                
 1        2012-02-24      4         3                
 1        2012-03-04      2         3              
 2        2012-03-15      1         5.6             
 2        2012-03-30      6         5.6             
 2        2012-04-07      10        5.6              
 3        2012-04-28      8         8
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. Trying to reverse engineer your query to determine what you think it should have returned is not going to be fun for anyone.

Comment: Also can you explain why you are trying to return things like CamMetric and AVG(CamMetric)? Do you want multiple rows with the same AVG on every row? If not, and you only want one row per counter/period, which CamMetric value should show? In order to avoid 18 more teeth-pulling questions like this, please furnish a few rows of sample data and desired results. You could even try a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3).

Comment: Please look at the EDITS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT [Counter], Period,
  CamMetric, 
  AvgCamMetric = AVG(CamMetric) OVER(PARTITION BY Counter),
  HfxMetric, 
  AvgHfxMetric = AVG(HfxMetric) OVER(PARTITION BY Counter)
  ... repeat for other metrics ...
FROM #tmpTransHrsData
GROUP BY [Counter], Period, CamMetric, HfxMetric;
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ac2b/1)

Comment: That did not seem to work for me. Do I first need to insert into Counter Column first or should I be able to do that all in the same query.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. Is this data in a table or a #temp table? Where does the data in the #temp table come from? What does "did not seem to work for me" mean? Did you look at the fiddle link, which produced exactly the results you wanted from the data you provided? If there is other information, you need to tell us; we can't guess.